# The area of the region $|x-ay| \le c$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$

Tags: calculus, geometry

> What is the area of the following region:
> $|x-ay| \le c$  for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$.
> Assume $c>0$.

We can also assume $|a|>1$ since it will not change the essence of the problem.

#### Progress

We get a strip embedded inside of the square.   I was wondering if there is a clean way to approach this, since there are many different sub cases.

Comment: As a first step: rewrite $|x-ay|\leq c$ without the absolute.

Comment: So, we get a strip embedded inside of the square. I knew that. I was wondering if there is a clean way to approach this, since there are many different sub cases.

Comment: It's not terribly obvious to me either. Maybe try flipping it around: How much of the unit square is not within the strip? I think that only requires finding the area of triangular corners.

Comment: You can also get a trapezoid, right?

Comment: @user63050 Not only a trapezoid, you can even get an irregular pentagon. For example, let $a=\frac32$ and $c=\frac12$.

Comment: One question mark is sufficient to indicate that a sentence is a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All sub cases.** Consider the strip embedded inside the square, as mentioned in the question, a bit modified though
(without loss of generality):
$$
\left|\, \cos(\phi) x + \sin(\phi) y\, \right| < c \quad
\mbox{with} \; c > 0 \; , \; 0 \le \phi < \pi
\quad \mbox{for} \; 0 \le x \le 1 \; , \; 0 \le y \le 1
$$
The vertices of the square are $\;(x_k,y_k) = \left\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\right\} , \; k=0,1,2,3\;$ .
Each of the vertices can be, in principle

- $(0)$ below the strip: $\;\cos(\phi) x_k + \sin(\phi) y_k \le -c$
- $(1)$ inside the strip: $\;-c < \cos(\phi) x_k + \sin(\phi) y_k < +c$
- $(2)$ above the strip: $\;+c \le \cos(\phi) x_k + \sin(\phi) y_k$

With exception of $(x_0,y_0) = (0,0)$ ; this vertex is always inside the strip. (You're lucky, otherwise you had to distinguish $3^4 = 81$ cases to begin with.) 
Now there are $3^3 = 27$ sub cases, in principle. They can be conveniently enumerated in a *base $3$ number system* . For example $210$ means that vertex $(1,0)$ is below the strip, vertex $(0,1)$ is inside the strip and vertex $(1,1)$ is above the strip: the number is read from the right to the left, i.e. towards the most significant digit (as usual). Because of the restriction $0 \le \phi < \pi$ only the cases $\;000 \cdots 111\;$ have
to be considered. The other cases are a mirror of these if $0 \le \phi < 2\pi$ is allowed eventually. With *one* noteworthy exception, though, namely $010 \not \equiv 212$ ($\color{red}{red}$) . So here comes:
$$
\begin{matrix}
000 & 001 & 002 & \color{red}{010} & 011 & 012 & 020 & 021 & 022 & 100 & 101 & 102 & 110 & 111 \\
222 & 221 & 220 & \color{red}{212} & 211 & 210 & 202 & 201 & 200 & 122 & 121 & 120 & 112 &     \\
    &     &     &     &     & NOP &     & NOP & NOP & NOP &     &     &     & 
\end{matrix}
$$
A picture says more than a thousand words:
[image]
It is seen that there are at most **11 sub cases** that must be taken into account.

**Area of polygon.** Though at the moment we have only an impression of what
the polygons look like, the *areas* of them have to be calculated, in the end.
[image]

So it's useful anyway to have a general method for doing just that. What we can do
is to draw ($\color{red}{red}$) lines from the origin $(0)$ to the vertices of
the polygon (six in our case) and sum up the areas of the (six) triangles $(0,1,2),(0,2,3),(0,3,4),(0,4,5),(0,5,6),(0,6,1)$ : see figure
at the bottom. The figure at the top shows how the area of just one triangle is
calculated, by using a determinant:
$$
\mbox{area}\,\Delta =
\frac{1}{2} det\begin{bmatrix}(x_2-x_1) & (y_2-y_1)\\(x_3-x_1) & (y_3-y_1)\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Note that, in general, the triangle areas thus calculated can be positive as well
as negative. And the latter is essential.
To be continued for the coordinates of the polygons, in anti-clockwise order.

**[Clipping problem](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/grads/h/Hao-wei.Hsieh/Haowei.Hsieh/mm.html).**
Usually a polygon (strip) is clipped against the square. But in our case, the square is clipped against a strip.
Once the ideas are clear, the algebra involved is very elementary. Hoping that the program below is more or less self-documentary:

```
program Q901259;

type
  point = record
    x,y : double;
  end;
  polygon = array of point;

function Area(round : polygon) : double;
{
  Area of polygon
}
var
  k,L : integer;
  Det,Opp : double;
  p,q : point;
begin
  Opp := 0;
  L := Length(round);
  if L > 0 then
  begin
    q := round[L-1];
    for k := 0 to L-1 do
    begin
      p := q;
      q := round[k];
      Det := (p.xq.y - q.xp.y);
      Opp := Opp + Det;
    end;
  end;
  Area := Opp/2;
end;

function let(x,y : double) : point;
var
  P : point;
begin
  P.x := x; P.y := y;
  let := P;
end;

function x_is_0(c,p : double) : point;
begin
  x_is_0 := let(0,c/sin(p));
end;

function x_is_1(c,p : double) : point;
begin
  x_is_1 := let(1,(c-cos(p))/sin(p));
end;

function y_is_0(c,p : double) : point;
begin
  y_is_0 := let(c/cos(p),0);
end;

function y_is_1(c,p : double) : point;
begin
  y_is_1 := let((c-sin(p))/cos(p),1);
end;

function Calculate(p,c : double) : double;
{
  Calculate area of strip inside square
   xcos(p) + ysin(p) = +/- c : strip
}
const
  choice : array[0..26] of integer =
  (0,1,2,3,4,-1,5,-1,-1,-1,6,7,8,9
  ,8,7,6,-1,-1,-1,5,-1,4,10,2,1,0);
var
  k,number,digit : integer;
  x,y : double;
  poly : polygon;
begin
  SetLength(poly,1);
  poly[0] := let(0,0);
  number := 0;

{Ternary number system }
  for k := 2 downto 0 do
  begin
    x := (k+1) mod 2;
    y := (k+1) div 2;
    digit := 1;
    if cos(p)*x+sin(p)*y < -c then digit := 0;
    if cos(p)*x+sin(p)*y > +c then digit := 2;
    number := number*3 + digit;
  end;

  {All sub cases }
  case choice[number] of
  0 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,3);
      poly[1] := y_is_0(+c,p);
      poly[2] := x_is_0(+c,p);
    end;
  1 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,4);
      poly[1] := let(1,0);
      poly[2] := x_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[3] := x_is_0(+c,p);
    end;
  2 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,5);
      poly[1] := y_is_0(-c,p);
      poly[2] := x_is_1(-c,p);
      poly[3] := x_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[4] := x_is_0(+c,p);
    end;
  3 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,4);
      poly[1] := y_is_0(-c,p);
      poly[2] := y_is_1(-c,p);
      poly[3] := let(0,1);
    end;
  4 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,5);
      poly[1] := let(1,0);
      poly[2] := x_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[3] := y_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[4] := let(0,1);
    end;
  5 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,5);
      poly[1] := y_is_0(-c,p);
      poly[2] := y_is_1(-c,p);
      poly[3] := y_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[4] := x_is_0(+c,p);
    end;
  6 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,5);
      poly[1] := let(1,0);
      poly[2] := let(1,1);
      poly[3] := y_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[4] := x_is_0(+c,p);
    end;
  7 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,6);
      poly[1] := y_is_0(-c,p);
      poly[2] := x_is_1(-c,p);
      poly[3] := let(1,1);
      poly[4] := y_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[5] := x_is_0(+c,p);
    end;
  8 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,5);
      poly[1] := y_is_0(-c,p);
      poly[2] := x_is_1(-c,p);
      poly[3] := let(1,1);
      poly[4] := let(0,1);
    end;
  9 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,4);
      poly[1] := let(1,0);
      poly[2] := let(1,1);
      poly[3] := let(0,1);
    end;
  10 :
    begin
      SetLength(poly,4);
      poly[1] := y_is_0(+c,p);
      poly[2] := y_is_1(+c,p);
      poly[3] := let(0,1);
    end;
  end;
  Calculate := Area(poly);
end;

begin
  Random; Random;
{ Test }
  while true do
  begin
    Writeln(Calculate(Random*Pi,Random));
    Readln;
  end;
end.
```

But: is it possible to have a solution *without* all the sub case jazz?
The answer is affirmative; that's how I actually tested the correctness of the above program.
Any area can be simply determined by *pixel counting* (not necessarily in a "real" picture).
Advantage: quick and dirty. Disadvantage: less exact than the sub case method.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Very impressive answer. Could explain how your transformation is with out loss of generality? Also, if I understand correctly your solution is numerical and there is no close form solution for the formula of the area, right?

Comment: Are you familiar with the _normal form_ of a line? We can scale the coefficients of a given linear equation by any (non-zero) constant and the result will be unchanged. So if $ax+by=c$ then we can divide the equation by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ to get $a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot x + b/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cdot y = c/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ . Now put $a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = \cos(\phi)$ and $b/\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = \sin(\phi)$ (: draw a rectangular triangle with sides $a,b$ and hypotenusa $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ to explain). The result is an equivalent equation $\;\cos(\phi)x+\sin(\phi)y=p$ .

Comment: When comparing your formula $|x-ay| \le c$ with the normed one $|\cos(\phi)x+\sin(\phi)y| \le c$ , we see that $|x - \left[-\tan(\phi)\right].y| \le c/\cos(\phi)$ . Here $\phi$ is the angle of the normal perpendicular to the strip with the x-axis. The slope of the line itself is $\theta = \phi-\pi/2$ . Hence, with "your" $c$ : $|y-\tan(\theta)x| \le c$ . Meaning that $|\tan(\theta)| < 1$ or $|\theta| < \pi/4$ . The range for $\phi$ in my answer is somewhat larger, namely $0 \le \phi < \pi$ , hence $|\theta| < \pi/2$ . Thus there rather is some gain of generality (twice) instead of a loss.

Comment: The fact that I've coded everything as a Pascal program does only mean that I can't find a sub-language in common mathematics to formulate these results properly. So the programming does _not_ at all mean that the result is _numerical_. In fact, the whole treatment is meant to be _exact_. Admittedly, there is _not one_ closed formula for the area; rather there are eleven "closed" formulas. (What
does "closed" mean in modern times anyway ?)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: **This approach leads nowhere.**

Let $S = \{(x,y) \in  [0,1]^2 : |x-ay|\leq c\}$. Consider the linear bijective map $$f(x,y) = (x-ay,y) = (u,v)$$ Then the $f(S) = \{(u,v) \in  [-a,1] \times [0,1] : |u| \leq c\} =: S_0$.

EDIT: **The following statement is wrong.**

The area $V(S_0) = 1 \cdot (\min \{c,1\}-\max\{-c,-a\})$ (rectangle), since $c>0$

Note that $S = f^{-1}(S_0)$ thus $$V(S) = |\det f^{-1}| V(S_0)= |\det f|^{-1} V(S_0) = 1\cdot V(S_0) = \min \{c,1\}-\max\{-c,-a\},$$ because $$\det f = \left| \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -a \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right| = 1.$$

I hope this is correct.

Comment: This approach seems promising? Could you please explain why your definition of $f(S)$ is the way it is? Also, $u$ can be negative, right? and you assume that it's positive, right?

Comment: Yes you are right, $u$ can be negative, I did not think of that. $f(S)$ is not a definition but a result of applying $f$ to $S$.

Comment: Would this change by much if we include $u$ to be negative??

Comment: I updated it now. Of course $S_0$ changed, and of course $V(S_0)$ so here you go.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could explain a little about $V(S)$. This formula that you are using for the volume where does it come from? Or rather what it is it called?

Comment: $f(S)$ is basically a rectangle, and $S$ a linearly transformed rectangle, that means it remains a parallelogram but can be rotated and squeezed. This 'formula' with $V$ can be viewed as variable transformation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables (which is a bit a overpowered) but there is also a theorem in linear algebra that is basically a special case of the mentioned one just for linear transformations, I'll see if i can find it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Comment: The idea is basically that the determinant of the map shows how mucht the volume changes. This is easy to understand when you know that the determinant is the product of all eigenvalues. So if one eigenvalue changed, the volume changes only in one dimension. If two eigenvalues lets say are doubled, the volume increases in two dimensions in this case by factor 2x2=4. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped and you can google 'Volume change under linear Transformation', I will let you know when I find a good resource.

Comment: Suppose, we try an example $|x-y| \le 0.5$. So, $a=1$ and $c=0.5$. If you where to compute the area of the strip we get $1-2\Delta$. Where $\Delta$ is the area of the upper triangle. So we get an area of Area=$1-0.5*0.5=0.75$. With your approach we get that the area is $ \min(0.5,1)-\max(-0.5,-1)=1$. It seems like something is missing? Who is wrong?

Comment: I see your point but I cannot spot the error in my solution yet. I calculate $f(S)$ wrong, but I do not see where the error lies.

Comment: Ok I think my approach will not work here. The condition $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$ maps to $(u+v,v) \in [0,1]^2$ and we have the same problem again. I am sorry, my approach was no help here...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. What is wrong with approach? Is it the mapping?